# How had the Avalon traveled 19 light years in just 30 years if it was moving at half the speed of light?

Tags: passengers

During the journey from Earth to Homestead II, Jim tries to send a message back to Earth. The computer informs him that it will take **19 years** for the message to reach Earth.

Since we know that the ship is travelling at 50% of lightspeed and since we know that it's been 30 years since the ship set off, shouldn't the message should reach Earth in ***15*** years rather than ***19***?

Comment: Most likely something about them traveling and sending the message at the same time, they were moving farther as the message was going towards earth.

Comment: They were traveling at half light speed, but you do not _attain_ light speed instantaneously without causing enormous damage to passengers. It takes time to build up. I do not think the actual acceleration during was mentioned in the movie.

Comment: @Cascabel - The problem isn't that they've been accelerating, it's that they've gone too far. The ship must have been traveling at more than 50% the speed of light in order to traverse 19 light years in just 30 actual years. 30/2 = 15.

Comment: The fact that Jim is awake is not a spoiler. It's literally the whole point of the film.

Comment: @Valorum lemme think about  the calcs. Im sure there is a plausible reason. There is also the possibility they were slowing down gradually.

Comment: @Cascabel - That was my instinct. We see them slingshotting a star to pick up speed and in the original script at one point they plough through a small nebula. I'm guessing the ship was traveling faster for the first few years of the journey and is gradually slowing down as they collide with interstellar dust.

Comment: At half light speed, the time differential would be no more than about 16%. Not enough to account for the discrepancy.

Comment: @girish - I'm at a loss why you keep trying to hide that behind a spoiler tag. It's not a spoiler!

Comment: @Valorum him trying to send a message to earth and they traveling at .5 c is kind off spoiler so I tried to hide it,

Comment: @Gallifreian as mentioned by valorum even Time differential wont account for the discrepancy.  So it's a legit question.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't worded that sue to time _dilation_ Earth won't see it for 19 years in ship time?  (or 19 years in Earth time)?

Comment: @Tim - It could be a failure on the part of the writer's to take into account the correct amount of dilation. In the original script, Jim says that the earliest communication will be "*With speed-of-light lag, fifty-six years. That’ll be from Earth.*"

Comment: Well, the ship has engines. Perhaps they were at max burn for the first few years, got up to .8 of lightspeed and have been gradually slowing down due to interstellar friction.

Comment: @Valorum Didnt they show the engines burning during the EVs, like when Pratt almost got burned up when his tether cut loose? So they should have been accelerating, right?

Comment: The second answer for the question I linked addresses that.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/otoEs.png

Comment: The fact that you can only justify marking this question as a duplicate if you reference a particular answer, is a huge screaming clue that the questions are **not**, in fact, duplicates. (Also "the second answer" is totally devoid of meaning in a Stack Exchange context.)

Comment: @Martha - I've amended [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/148912/20774) (on the dupe) in order to more specifically address the point raised above.

Comment: @Valorum: that rather misses the point, namely that answers do not and cannot make *questions* into duplicates. (I know, I know, it's a long-entrenched... idiosyncrasy of this site, but that doesn't mean I can't push back against it every now and then, because no matter how long-entrenched it is, it's still wrong.)

Comment: Maybe the people on the other end only check their email every four years.